# django admin printer friendly stylesheet

Tags: css, django, django-admin

Has anyone got or know if a printer friendly css file is available for the Django Admin site?

Comment: what do you mean by a printer friendly CSS?

Comment: @anand One which hides to filters and buttons etc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add in a print CSS stylesheet for the admin, add this to your `admin/base_site.html` template:

```
{% block extrastyle %}
   {{block.super}}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/your/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" charset="utf-8">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I know you can do that but I was trying to find if anyone had wrote the css file to be used (e.g. print.css from you example).  One which hides to filters and buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to output the contents of the admin site, I would suggest exporting it as a CSV file first and then printing from  spreadsheet software.

I have used this in the past and recommend it: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/